# How do I install python packages with poetry?

Tags: python, installation, module, package, python-poetry

Im migrating projects to poetry but have a problem here.
This is simple project, not many modules needed. I installed poetry, used `poetry add` to add few packages required and then ran `poetry install` but it seems like its not installing pandas in my venv. My `pyproject.toml` looks like this:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "***"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["***"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
pandas = "^1.2.2"
numpy = "^1.20.1"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Then I run:

```
PS C:\****> poetry install 
Installing dependencies from lock file

No dependencies to install or update
```

And finally when I want to run main.py script which uses pandas it says there is no module named pandas:

```
PS C:\***> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\***\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from output import QuestionnaireWrangler, PaymentProbabilityIndex
  File "C:\***\output.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Am i missing some piece of puzzle here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

after `poetry install` run:

```
poetry python main.py
```

or

```
poetry shell
python main.py
```

for production add the follow lines in your pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
my_app = 'mypackage.my_module:my_method'
```

run:

```
poetry build
```

after:

```
pip install my_project.whl # or tar
```

then run `my_app` in shell or bash

I hope I've helped

Answer (score 14):

You can try `poetry add <package-name>`. It will add a new package at lock file.

Comment: [from poetry docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add): The `add` command adds required packages to your pyproject.toml **and installs** them.